# Getting the package name

Tags: android, database

I have a library class that should access a file in the data/data/package/databases folder.

The problem is that the package name changes depending on what app is using the library, so I can't hard code it... How can I get the package name, or the path to the databases folder at run time?

Thanks

Answer (score 12, accepted):

Use [`Context.getPackageName()`](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/content/Context.html#getPackageName%28%29).

Comment: AH HA! I knew it would be something simple. The only results google would return was for finding the package name from an APK. Thanks!